# Find pairs of numbers in an array with multiplication 256 javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to find pairs of numbers `a b` where `a * b = 256` in the array `[128, 2, 4, 16, 2, 128, 64, 4, 7, 4, 64]` and return their indices. However I would like to eliminate duplicates, for example if the result already contains `0 1` then `0 4` should not be added, since they both represent `128*2`

Expected output is two pairs of indices, one for `128 * 2` and one for `64 * 4`, for example `0 1, 6 7`

```
let arr = [128, 2, 4, 16, 2, 128, 64, 4, 7, 4, 64];
let a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i] * arr[j] === 256) {
      console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: what about more than the same value in the result set?

Comment: i tried for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i] * arr[j] === 256) {
      console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
    
  }
  
}

Comment: Please edit the question with that code so it can be formatted and easily read by all instead of a big blob in a comment

Comment: let arr = [128, 2, 4, 16, 2, 128, 64, 4, 7, 4, 64];
let a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i] * arr[j] === 256) {
      console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
    
  }
  
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double for loop

The first `i` goes from `0` to `length - 1` 
The second goes from `i + 1` to the end of the array

This way you get all possible combinations

Then to check for duplicates you can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if there's already a pair with say `128 2` or `2 128`

**edit**

I changed the way you loop over the objects to `0 1, 1 2, 2 3 ... 0 2, 1 3, ...` as requested

```js
const data = [128, 2, 4, 16, 2, 128, 64, 4, 7, 4, 64];
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[j-i-1] * data[j] == 256) {
      if (!result.some(x =>
          (data[x[0]] == data[j-i-1] && data[x[1]] == data[j]) ||
          (data[x[1]] == data[j-i-1] && data[x[0]] == data[j]))) {
        result.push([j-i-1, j]);
      }
    }
  }
}

result.forEach(x => console.log(x[0], x[1]))
```

Comment: i tried like you, but can not eliminate pairs of duplicate numbers.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific what you mean with duplicate numbers, do you mean if there is already a pair with `128 2` for example don't add any other indices of that pair? for example only add `0 1` and not `0 4`

Comment: sorry , I wasn't specific. result 128 2 at 0 1, 64 4 at 6 7 not 2 6

Comment: do you need this exact result? The output is both a pair of 128x2 and 64x4. To get `6 7` instead of  `2 6` you simply loop over the array differently but the result is the same

Comment: can you give me exact result, I don't understand at all what you mean